# Jenkins with the Measurement Plots plugin does not plot measurements

Tags: plugins, jenkins, xunit

Is there anyone who was successful in getting a plot using Jenkins with the [Measurement Plots](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Measurement+Plots+Plugin) plugin and a xUnit test results file with the  tags?

If yes, I'd like to see a sample of a working xUnit file and get from you any tips you may have about configuring Jenkins and the appropriate Jenkins job to accomplish this feat.

Comment: The measurement plots plugin reads stdout and stderr. Do you want to output the xUnit test result file to stdout?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with the measurement plots plugin? I'm trying to use it but have had no success.

Comment: I didn't get it to run properly. See comment to the answer below.

Answer (score 6):

I just figured it out with some help from the author.  The trick is to escape the XML inside the XML and use `<system-out>`to feed the Measurements Plot plugin.  The steps below shows how to use it and feed various values into the plugin:

1. Create a New Job in Jenkins  "free-style software project"
2. Add String Parameter VALUETEST
3. Add Build step  Execute Shell Command is the code below.
4. Add Post-build Action:  Publish JUnit

   1. Test report XMLs: testdetail-*.xml
   2. Check Retain long staandard output
   3. Check Measurement Plots
5. Save and Build Now.
6. Plot will appear under Test Results.  You need more than one run for the plot appear.

Execute Shell Command:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' > testdetail-lcov.xml
echo '<testsuites name="CodeAnalysis" tests="2" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0">' >> testdetail-lcov.xml

echo '<testsuite  name="Suite" tests="1" >' >> testdetail-lcov.xml
echo '<testcase   name="Case" status="run" time="0" classname="Suite">' >> testdetail-lcov.xml
echo '</testcase></testsuite>' >> testdetail-lcov.xml

echo '<testsuite  tests="1" >' >> testdetail-lcov.xml
echo '<testcase   name="Lcov" status="run" time="0" classname="CodeAnalysis.Coverage">' >> testdetail-lcov.xml

echo '<system-out>' >> testdetail-lcov.xml
echo "&lt;measurement&gt;&lt;name&gt;Line Coverage&lt;/name&gt;&lt;value&gt;$VALUETEST&lt;/value&gt;&lt;/measurement&gt;" >> testdetail-lcov.xml
echo '</system-out>' >> testdetail-lcov.xml

echo '</testcase></testsuite></testsuites>' >> testdetail-lcov.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for these details.
I used the above shell command to generate a junit testresult with measurement data for the measurement plot plugin. It seems to record it (it displays the name and value on the testcase result page).
However when I click on the link of the measurement name, then I get a "Connection refused". So it seems the plugin is buggy ... Can anybody confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

The Measurement Plots plugin is designed to take values out of standard output and error buffer and should not be used to plot stats and details of test frameworks.

For xUnit there is a [xUnit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) that does the job quite nicely. Unless you want to handle some very specific type of data/information used by xUnit, this should the trick of nicely showing the tests results.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some examples (or links to examples) how you can get plots of measurements with the xUnit plugin? It appears to me that it can just handle "passed/failed" results.